# What is the meaning of back channel or backdoor in a program?

Tags: backdoor

What is backdoor and why is it created in first place if it creates additional unnecessary risk? You might want to take up an example to explain it in detail.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. Please do [some reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backdoor_(computing)), and then if you have additional questions, feel free to come back and ask a more specific question, or at least explain the part that is confusing to you.

Answer (score 1):

A backdoor is a way to get into something, like an application. Many are written as administrative tools so admins can access a system even if users have broken the main entrance.

Some backdoors are secret, so the person running server or application doesn't even know someone has access to it. This can be malicious - obviously for an attacker, having a route in is useful but if the victim knows about it then they can try to fix it.